# Desktop application not respecting action shortcuts on a dialog

Tags: flutter, keyboard-shortcuts, flutter-desktop

i'm working with a flutter desktop application and it has a page that depends a lot on shortcuts. In the front page it works wonders. The problem is when i open a dialog (the page has 2). The shortcuts dont work anymore. I tried init the dialog shortcuts both when the main page is built and when the dialog is built, both didnt work. I also tried **FocusableActionDetector** with single calls from the shortcut/actions methods, without any luck.
If u need me to post more code, pls let me know.
OBS:I'm using cubit to manage state.

-page build

```
class VendaScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const VendaScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ActivityListener<VendaCubit, VendaState>(
      child: Shortcuts(
        shortcuts: VendaHelper().mainShortCuts(),
        child: Actions(
          actions: VendaHelper().mainActions(context),
          child: const ScaffoldWidget(
            appBar: AppBarWidget(title: 'Venda'),
            body: VendaScreenBody(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

-shortcuts and actions

```
   Map<ShortcutActivator, Intent> mainShortCuts() {
    return {
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.f7): FocusCod(),
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.f6): FocusName(),
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.f8): FocusQtd(),
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.f2): CancelBuy(),
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.f10): EndVenda(),
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter): AddItem(),
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.tab): AddItem(),
    };
  }

  Map<Type, Action<Intent>> mainActions(BuildContext context) {
    final _cubit = context.read<VendaCubit>();
    return {
      FocusCod: CallbackAction<FocusCod>(
        onInvoke: (_) => _cubit.focusCodNode(),
      ),
      FocusName: CallbackAction<FocusName>(
        onInvoke: (_) => _cubit.focusNameNode(context),
      ),
      FocusQtd: CallbackAction<FocusQtd>(
        onInvoke: (_) => _cubit.focusQtdNode(),
      ),
      AddItem: CallbackAction<AddItem>(
        onInvoke: (_) => _cubit.addItem(context),
      ),
      CancelBuy: CallbackAction<CancelBuy>(
        onInvoke: (_) => _cubit.cancelVenda(),
      ),
      EndVenda: CallbackAction<EndVenda>(
          onInvoke: (_) => VendaEndDialog.show(context)),
    };
  }
```

-dialog

```
class VendaEndDialog {
  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {
    final _cubit = context.read<VendaCubit>();
    return await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return BlocProvider<VendaCubit>.value(
          value: _cubit,
          child: const EndDialogWidget(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class EndDialogWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const EndDialogWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DialogWidget(
      size: DialogSize.lg,
      title: Messages.of('end.finalizar'),
      actions: [
        _return(context),
        _finalizarPedido(context),
        _finalizarNFCe(context),
      ],
      child: _body(context),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Focus widget/class of Flutter to Focus on the child where you want to implement your shortcuts.

Set:

```
Focus(autofocus: true, child: WidgetUsedForShortcut),
```

[image: Focus added in this example in Shortcuts class]

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Shortcuts-class.html

Focus, Actions and Shortcuts Widgets/ Classes are relative to each other.